# Strange binding permanence between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a project in which you write a note in a formulary. Then, you submit that note into an information container (now it's just an array for testing purposes, but it's intended to be a DB later).

The formulary has the following controller:

```
app.controller('controlFormulario', ['$scope', 'SubmitService', function($scope, submitService) {

  $scope.formData = {
    "titulo":"",
    "texto":"",
    "fecha": new Date()
  };

    $scope.submit = function() {
        var temp = $scope.formData;
        submitService.prepForBroadcast(temp);


    }
// more things we don't need now
```

... which is bound to this part of the DOM, which is added into it, via a directive:

```
<form ng-controller="controlFormulario as formCtrl">
        <div class="element">
          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': formData.titulo.length > 50 }">
            <label for="inputTitulo">Título</label>
            <input type="titulo" class="form-control"  id="inputTitulo" ng-model="formData.titulo">
            <span ng-show="formData.titulo.length > 50" id="helpBlock" class="help-block">El título no puede exceder los 50 caracteres.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputTexto">Texto</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="inputTexto" ng-model="formData.texto"></textarea>

          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
            <input type="fecha" class="form-control" id="fecha" ng-model="formData.fecha" disabled>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" >
            <button  class="btn btn-primary" style="height:35px;width:100px;float:right;"  id="submit"
            ng-disabled="isDisabled()" ng-click="submit()">
            Enviar
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="note" ng-show="formData.titulo.length > 0">
         <div class="title" ng-model="formData.titulo" class="title">{{formData.titulo | limitTo:50}}</div>
         <div class="text" ng-model="formData.texto" class="text">{{formData.texto}}</div>
         <div class="date" ng-model="formData.fecha" class="date">{{formData.fecha | date}}</div>
        </div>

      </form>
```

This is my directive (I don't think it's really needed, but just in case):

```
app.directive('formulario', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', // C: class, E: element, M: comments, A: attributes
    templateUrl: 'modules/formulario.html',

  };
}]);
```

I use a service for passing the data between the previous controller, and the note controller (which controls the note objects of the array). This is the service:

```
app.factory('SubmitService', function($rootScope) {
    var data = {};

    data.prepForBroadcast = function(recvData) {
        data.data = recvData;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };

    data.broadcastItem = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return data;
});
```

... and I receive it in this part of my note controller:

```
app.controller('noteController', ['$scope', 'SubmitService', function($scope, submitService) {

  var nc = this;

    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        nc.pruebaNota.push(submitService.data);
        $scope.formData.titulo = "";
        $scope.formData.texto= "";
        $scope.formData.fecha = new Date();
    });

// more things, the array, etc...
```

Ok. This should work, and it does, but something strange happens: as you can see, the preview note is binded with ng-model to the form. That works great, ok. But when I submit the form, the new note object **keeps bound to the form** (so if I delete the form text, the note appears in blank, and if I write something, it gets automatically updated both in the preview note, and the new note), when there isn't any relation between them. The new note, which appears dynamically on the screen, shouldn't be bound to anything.

Am I doing something wrong? Some help would be really nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting something really important. Memory address. So, the rought idea is something like: imagine that `$scope.formData` is in the address **123123**. You first create a `temp` var pointing to **123123** then you send it to the service and the service holds the same address **123123** into `data.data`.

Then in your second controller you say: hey, I want to work with that `data.data` (AKA your data in **123123**) you have `SubmitService`.

Now when you modify `$scope.formData` again, you are updating what you have in that **123123** and everything that is "looking" into that address will be updated.

That is the rough idea. To point it simple, you're modifying the same piece of information everywhere.

See it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/zcEDQLHFWxYg4D7FqlmP?p=preview

As a AWolf suggested, to fix this issue, you can use `angular.copy` like this:

```
nc.pruebaNota.push(angular.copy(submitService.data));
```

Comment: Good answer/explanation for variable references. But a fix for the problem would be nice. You could add `angular.copy(...)` to create a copy of the variable. Please have a look at this updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sKp0UU2sDBpzk1iXJtJD?p=preview).

Comment: Indeed, I was too deep into the explanation that I forgot. Will update.

Comment: You're right, I kind of had this clue, but the thing is... how do I solve it? It is binding the array's last object to the form, but that binding is unintentional. I just want to push the new information, and being able to add a new one if I want to.

Comment: Thank you, AWolf! That fixes the problem!

Comment: Nice. I sometimes forget that I am in SO and you need concrete solutions. I am more into teach what the problem is so you can fix it yourself :P